# Chart.js displays bar as overflown even below the x-axis

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart

I don't want this to happen, it happens sometimes, not always. How to avoid the bar filling over bottom side of the x axis, when it is actually not negative at all even! Take a look at screenshot here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved magically by setting the ticks minimum in the chart's options.